# What are the effects of code bloat in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, optimization

I can't really find any other explanation other than "It's unnecessarily longer binaries". But what does that really mean? How is having more executable code under the hood of a program bad? Ignoring readability benefits that is.

For example:

```
template<int A, int B, int C>
void doSomething(){

    if( A == 1 ){
        ...
    }    
    if( B == 1 ){
        ...
    }
    if( C == 1 ){
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case there are a maximum of 3*3=9 possible combinations of the way that function can execute code, ignoring optimizations of course.

So what's the big deal? It saves me from lots of readability headaches and sometimes compacts how much I write.

Comment: "Code bloat" aside, if you're doing anything conditional with template parameters, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Long binary code may have a bad locality property, leading to a low rate of cache hit.

Comment: @user657267 It was an example. Assume that I am passing in enumerations instead.

Comment: For me you would have to define exactly what you mean by "code bloat" in the context of your question.

Comment: Code bloat was a problem 20 years ago, but now any reasonably sized program is going to fit into cache. I don't worry about it anymore.

Comment: @Galik Well since there are more than one ways to execute the function, and if I understand templates properly, then the compiler should end up dealing with multiple instances of the function with each doing something different based on what we passed into the templates. So we have more executable code binaries in the long run. That. Lingxi understood.

Comment: I believe 'code bloat' refers to carrying in your executable code that does 1000 things, when you only need 3 or 4. This may happen in many cases when some library calls you use have dependencies in quite a few more library-internal modules that you do not really need but have to carry anyway since you are using those 3-4 modules that need them. There can be quite a few more ways to 'bloat up' your code by using wrong coding style, or writing unnecessary code that could be otherwise optimized.

Comment: @sgtHale I think anyone trying to answer this question already has to assume more than should be expected. If you specifically mean code bloat due to template instantiations you should make that clear. Also I'm not sure how replacing those `int`s with `enum`s is supposed to help, if you're performing runtime conditional operations on template parameters...you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @user657267 Yes that is what I am referring to.

Comment: I would question whether there *is* any code bloat here. Any decently optimizing compiler should see the constant template arguments and tests, and remove all the unreachable code. On the other hand you're still going to generate 9 versions of the template function. Do you really need that? Do you have a good reason for making it a template function at all, instead of a function with three arguments?

Comment: Unless/until you actually observe your program running too slowly (or taking up too much memory, or some other unwanted behavior) there's little point in worrying about it.  Premature optimization usually causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: Say, your chip has 64K very fast SRAM, by very fast I mean guaranteed less than 10 cycle latency. Growing the binary size from 62K to 65K forces you to move the executable out to main DRAM, causing a performance disaster.

Comment: I think adding "Ignoring readability benefits that is" to the question eliminates the biggest problem with code bloat. Most of the time, if you have to choose between readability and performance, readability is the right choice. The only time fast-and-ugly beats readable-and-fast-enough is deep in the inner loop of code that is extremely performance sensitive.